# Error when building next.js app: Can't resolve 'next/head'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting the below error when doing `next build` in my next.js app, after it's been working fine with just `next` (or `npm run dev`).

The error:

```
$ next build
The module 'react-dom' was not found. Next.js requires that you include it in 'dependencies' of your 'package.json'. To add it, run 'npm install --save react-dom'
Creating an optimized production build ...

> Using external babel configuration
> Location: "../.babelrc"
Failed to compile.

./pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'next/head' in '../pages'

> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at build (.../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:7:847)
```

I started my project by cloning Material UI's next.js example and just use that as it seems updated:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs

However, thinking I just may of have an outdated or broken build, I re-cloned the next.js example and did `next build` as well, without modifying any files and I get the same error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just cloned that next.js example and it worked both with npm run dev, as well as npm run build->npm run start.

Judging by your error, I would check that `"react-dom": "latest"` is present in your `package.json`'s dependencies. Did you run npm install after cloning the example?

Comment: Any reason why it'll work with `npm run build` and not `next build`?

Comment: I've got no real clue, but I'm guessing that it has to do with the way next is being run? `npx next build` followed by `npx next start` seems to work fine

Comment: Is `npx next start` is what i'd run for production?

Comment: Great question! Unsure, but I believe the correct way is to do it through the npm scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to Just rerun these two commands again then your project will successfully Run. I also faced this problem but I got the solution.

1. npm i
2. yarn install

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when I included my nextjs app in a yarn workspace. I got around the issue by deleting the following directories in my nextjs app:

- *node_modules*
- *.next*
- *build*

After removing them I ran `yarn` from the repo directory and started the nextjs app back up and it was working again.